# Interesting question regarding congruences of prime power sums

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

> For prime $p$ and $a \in Z$, let $l$ be any prime dividing $a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}+\cdots+a+1$. Show that the order of $a$ modulo $l$ is either $1$ or $p$, and therefore that either $l=p$ or $l \equiv 1 \pmod p$

Does anyone have any pointers with this question? I'm afraid I really don't have any kind of ideas whatsoever...

Comment: Note that $(a^p-1)=(a-1)(a^{p-1}+\cdots+a+1)$. So if $\ell$ divides $a^p-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the sum is $\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$. Thus $\ell|(a^p-1)$, so $a^p\equiv 1\pmod{\ell}$. By definition of order, the order $o(a)$ must divide $p$, it follows that $o(a)\in \{1,p\}$.